# What vectorial file format is usually used for working well with both CorelDraw and Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corel-draw, file-format

I am creating some templates and upload them to my website for people to used them in whatever software they have. The file needs to be vectorial and open the dimensions correctly in every program (page size, guidelines, shapes, etc)
I know that a PDF created in Illustrator could create problems in Corel Draw and I assume could be vice-versa, as PDF being an Illustrator file.
I am using Corel Draw X6 to create this templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn’t go down the road of trying to support any one particular vector drawing application, because there are so many different apps today. And even any one app may have multiple versions of its format. You would have to buy CorelDraw and Sketch and Graphic and many others to support all of the users who may want your template.

There are three standardized vector graphics formats for sharing: SVG, PDF, and EPS. Note that the standard PDF is not an Illustrator PDF you Save out of Illustrator, it is a standard PDF that you Export out of Illustrator and choose a standardized version of PDF. All three of these formats can be created with the Illustrator that you already have. It is a manageable, practical project to create and share all three.

However, I wouldn’t do that either. I would publish just an SVG, for the following reasons:

- you can focus all your effort on making (and revising, and maintaining) the very best SVG for each template with exactly the features that you feel are important to share with the user
- SVG imports into almost any vector editor, and can even be edited as text in a text editor where a user could replace the boilerplate text with their own text and that might be all they need to do for some templates
- SVG supports layers, real drop shadows (not bitmap renders) and other effects, editable text blocks, and other features you expect to be able to share with your users
- you don’t have to offer a download at all, you can just place the SVG into a Web page and the user can see the native SVG and then just save it like they would a PNG or JPEG that they like — this skips the zip step that is confusing for some and really hard in some situations like on iPads where the user hasn’t installed an app that can download and decode zips
- your entire published work, including the Web page where you offer these templates, ends up being Web-native and future-proofed — if you make these templates for a year and then stop, you could leave them up and people will still be using them 10 years from now with no further work from you
- SVG is a vendor neutral standard that is made for sharing, so you are doing the right thing by sharing in this format, and rewarding software developers who built good SVG support into their apps, enabling people like you to share templates like this broadly with all interested users
- SVG file size is very, very small, so you will be able to serve more users with the same server
- SVG is made for modern online publishing, not just for print, so it has animation and interactivity features that you might enjoy exploring and sharing with users

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with some specific effects, normally some kind of gradients and shadows that could be rasterized in the PDF file.

If you use just flat "design" you will have less issues.

But in reality there is no universal file format. If you make a template for Corel it would be nice to have well organized layers. A PDF or EPS file format could loose that information. A PDF also trims blocks of text into single lines.

Probably the best option is to provide a zip file with 2 file formats. A Corel file and an AI file.

Comment: So, an AI file exported from CorelDraw you would say that is safe for using in Illustrator? I am refering to flat design file, no effects, no shadows, no gradients. I am asking because I only have Draw to work with.

Comment: The zip file is what I went for, with CDR and AI. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Many stock illustration websites use `*.EPS` as a format to distribute vector files, but as Rafael mentioned in the other answer, there is no universal option. Make sure to leave your shapes and objects as simple as possible, without resorting to effects and features that you know are unique to a specific program.

Also, consider those files as production files, and always keep your original resources in a native format (such as `*.AI` in Illustrator and `*.CDR` in CorelDRAW) to make sure you won't lose any configuration that may be rasterized or transformed with `*.EPS` and `*.PDF` conversions.